# Serverless deploying to AWS, Azure or GCP

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, serverless-framework, serverless

Does anyone using the Serverless framework know if it's possible to use the same serverless deploy file to deploy to all three cloud providers if the underlying code is capable?

Or are the serverless files specific to each cloud provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all your function code are provider agnostic...

Each provider have their own specific way of defining and configuring things so you would expect that the low-level details of the `serverless.yml` file for each would be different.

That being said, the high-level properties of the `serverless.yml` are pretty much common for most, if not all, providers.

```
service:


provider:


plugins:


functions:
```

This would allow you to have one `serverless.yml` for all providers that simply references other YAML files depending on an environment variable. Assuming you have `serverless-aws.yml`, `serverless-azure.yml`, and `serverless-google.yml` for your provider-specific configuration, you should be able to use this in your `serverless.yml`,

```
service: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):service}


plugins: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):plugins}


provider: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):provider}


functions:
    getSomething: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):functions.getSomething}
    createSomething: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):functions.createSomething}
    updateSomething: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):functions.updateSomething}
    deleteSomething: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):functions.deleteSomething}
```

Whenever you deploy, you can choose which provider to use by specifying the `PROVIDER` environment variable.

```
$ PROVIDER=aws sls deploy    # Deploys to AWS

$ PROVIDER=azure sls deploy    # Deploys to Azure

$ PROVIDER=google sls deploy    # Deploys to GCP
```

Answer (score 1):

@dashmug's answer *should* work but doesn't. If you try to include the entire provider section, it doesn't get evaluated -- i.e. `srs print` just spits out the un-evaluated expression:

```
provider: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):provider}
```

Trying to parameterize each key doesn't work because it changes to order, which seems to cause the deploy to fail:

```
//serverless.yml
...
provider:
  name: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):provider.name}
  runtime: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):provider.runtime}
  stage: ${file(serverless-${env:PROVIDER}.yml):provider.stage}
...
```

Results in this:

```
> sls print
service: my-crossplatform-service
provider:
  stage: prod
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
```

I ended up just maintaining separate `serverless.yml` files and deploying with a little bash script that copies the appropriate file first:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
  echo "copying serverless-$1.yml to serverless.yml and running serverless deploy"
  cp serverless-$1.yml serverless.yml && sls deploy
else
    echo "Please append provider, like 'deploy.sh aws' or 'deploy.sh azure'"
fi
```

Really wish you could just specify the config file as a deploy option, as requested here: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/4485